# UNIX: How to extract date from a variable storing a UNIX DATE

Tags: shell, date, string

I am facing following issue:

Input:

```
F=`date +%Y%m%d`

echo $F
```

Output:

```
F=20131231
```

But when trying this(File Name:A.sh):

```
C=`date`

G=`$C +%Y%m%d`

echo $C

echo $G

Output:

A.sh[6]: Tue:  not found

Tue Dec 31 06:14:12 EST 2013
```

I want to pass the date in a variable and then extract only date in a specific format.